# Improve Link Missing From Suggested Edit

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I was reviewing this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2813579) and noticed that the improve link is missing for this particular edit. If I move on to another edit it shows up just fine but for this particular edit it doesn't show up.

What cases would case this link to not appear on a suggested edit?

[image: Where is it?]

Comment: I see an "improve" button for that edit, so whatever is going on seems to be an issue with you/your account, not that suggested edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that this is because [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495100/multiply-data-from-database-to-my-inputbox) was deleted.

- 18:03:02 question asked
- 18:07:33 suggested edit
- 18:07:47 post deleted by the author
- 18:13:36 suggested edit approved

It looks like the suggested edit review code doesn't check whether the post has been deleted. The logic around the Improve button however does, because it hooks onto the normal edit logic. Since you do not have enough reputation to view this post, you aren't allowed to edit it either, so you don't get an Improve button.

This isn't the only case when you don't get an Improve button. The common case is for a tag wiki, if you have the privilege to [review tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (5k rep on graduated sites) but not to [edit tag wikis without supervision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20k rep on graduated sites).

Servy has enough reputation to view (and edit) deleted posts, so he could have edited the post directly, so he got an Improve button.